# Blog - Number of posts

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I have a blog where it is supposed to show up two grid columns and six posts but it only shows five,.In addition I have a button to load more posts so when i click it it shows five more (it should be six too), so there are enough posts to load six. It uses a wordpress plugin named fusin-core.

There are two things that I found:
First I tried to change this on back-end page with this: 
 `[blog number_posts="6" offset="" cat_slug="" exclude_cats="" show_title="yes" title_link="yes" thumbnail="yes" excerpt="yes" excerpt_length="35" meta_all="no" meta_author="no" meta_categories="yes" meta_comments="no" meta_date="yes" meta_link="yes" meta_tags="no" paging="yes" scrolling="pagination" strip_html="yes" blog_grid_columns="2" blog_grid_column_spacing="40" layout="large" class="" id=""][/blog]`  
I tried to put more but it just ignore it
Then looking for php's files I found a class named class-blog.php inside of plugins (fusion-core) and there are some arguments that I tried to change but without result.

`$defaults = FusionCore_Plugin::set_shortcode_defaults(
            array(
                'class'                     => '',
                'id'                        => '',
                'blog_grid_column_spacing'  => '40',
                'blog_grid_columns'         => '3',
                'cat_slug'                  => '',
                'excerpt'                   => 'yes',
                'excerpt_length'            => '',`

```
            'exclude_cats'              => '',
            'layout'                    => 'large',
            'meta_all'                  => 'yes',
            'meta_author'               => 'yes',
            'meta_categories'           => 'yes',
            'meta_comments'             => 'yes',
            'meta_date'                 => 'yes',
            'meta_link'                 => 'yes',
            'meta_read'                 => 'yes',
            'meta_tags'                 => 'no',
            'number_posts'              => '6',
            'offset'                    => '',
            'order'                     => 'DESC',
            'orderby'                   => 'date',
            'paging'                    => 'yes',
            'show_title'                => 'yes',
            'scrolling'                 => 'infinite',
            'strip_html'                => 'yes',
            'thumbnail'                 => 'yes',
            'title_link'                => 'yes',
            'posts_per_page'            => '6',
            'taxonomy'                  => 'category',

            'excerpt_words'             => '50',    //deprecated
            'title'                     => '',  // deprecated               
        ), $args
    );
```

It should show up two grid columns with six post and then load 6 more. I will apreciatte if you give me a hand.

There is how it sees:
https://netcloudengineering.com/blog-redes-telecomunicaciones-ciberseguridad/?lang=en

Answer (score 0):

use this function. I hope its working for you.

```
function wpdocs_five_posts_on_homepage( $query ) {
if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 6 );
} } add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpdocs_five_posts_on_homepage' );
```

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer. It does not work for me, it seems like I am touching a wrong file because whatever change I do do not change nothing @HarshKhare